# csv file doesn't get created if i run a python file on CMD

Tags: python, pandas, csv, cmd

I have a python file that writes data to a csv file.
I have another python file that reads the data from the csv file and shows it on a plot.

when i try to run the first file on CMD the csv file doesn't get created while the values that should have been written to the csv file are printed.

when i use IDLE to run the first file i can see that the csv file is being created and the data is being written to it. and in addition i can see the changes in the csv file using the second file since it checks for updates every second.

does anyone know why it won't work with CMD?

been working with python for 4 months

**first file:**

```py
import csv
import random
import time

x_value = 0
total_1 = 1000
total_2 = 1000

fieldnames = ["x_value", "total_1", "total_2"]


with open('data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

while True:

    with open('data.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        info = {
            "x_value": x_value,
            "total_1": total_1,
            "total_2": total_2
        }

        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        print(x_value, total_1, total_2)

        x_value += 1
        total_1 = total_1 + random.randint(-6, 8)
        total_2 = total_2 + random.randint(-5, 6)

    time.sleep(1)
```

**second file:**

```py
import random
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    y1 = data['total_1']
    y2 = data['total_2']

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x,y1,label = 'Channel 1')
    plt.plot(x,y2,label = 'Channel 2')

    plt.legend(loc= 'upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(),animate,interval= 1000)    

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

thanks

btw im running python 3.7.2

Comment: Please add, as text, the cmd.exe command you are entering and the output, including error messages. The firstfile.py is opening and writing to the .csv file every second. Is that intended?

Comment: yes, it's intended to open and write every second to see the live changes in the data. so this is what i write in CMD: "python "path to the file". i can copy to path here but i just go to file, hold shift and right click to copy the path. i'm not getting any error messages in CMD. i can see the values being printed in CMD but the csv file doesn't get created.

Comment: Try adding `print(os.getcwd())` to both files to confirm which folder is being used. You will need to `import os` also.

Comment: so i found out where the csv file was being created while running from CMD.. it's being written to the user directory of my PC instead of the current folder i'm in. how can i make sure that CMD writes the new file to the same folder of the python file?